# Parsing artist and track information from the output of ncmpcpp

Tags: bash, piping

I am trying to parse the output from ncmpcpp to get the artist and track title.

The output from `ncmpcpp --now-playing` takes the form of

```
(MM:SS) %ARTIST% - %TRACKTITLE%
```

Example:

```
(4:46) A Perfect Circle - Imagine
```

Using traditional piping tools available on linux(head, sed, awk, grep) how can I get rid of the info in parentheses and parse the rest?

I have tried using awk, but it is ineffective as band names can contain spaces and thus %ARTIST% can be considered several arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that --now-playing takes additional parameter - format of the output string, so you basically need to invoke `ncmpcpp --now-playing "%a - %t"` (or similar) to get what you want.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! I did not know it took arguments. Thanks a lot, good sir!

Answer (score 0):

If your artist name contains a hyphen, this will fail, but so will anything that relies on the hyphen being the delimiter between the artist and the title

```
echo "(32:32) Album artist - This is the title - it's hyphenated" |
    awk 'match($0, /^\([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}\)\s([^-]*)\s-\s(.*)/, r) {print r[1];print r[2]}'
```

Output:

```
Album artist
This is the title - it's hyphenated
```

**EDIT**

I may have misunderstood your question - if you don't need the artist and title in separate fields, just use this to strip off the time:

```
echo "(4:46) A Perfect Circle - Imagine" | sed -r 's/^\([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}\)\s//'
```

Output:

```
A Perfect Circle - Imagine
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, with your example it puts out the info on 2 lines, but I really need it on one. I also tried to do it with the actual output from `ncmpcpp`(which I've added to the question) and it doesn't work with the example. When I replace `(32:32) Album artist - This is the title - it's hyphenated` with `(4:46) A Perfect Circle - Imagine`, I get no output at all.

Comment: The `print` commands are just an example. Do whatever you want with them. You could replace them with `print r[1] r[2]`, for example. I've updated the regex to handle single digits in the minutes field. That's the `[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}` part - i.e 1 or 2 digits followed by a colon, followed by 2 more digits.